# Compiling HTML, CSS, and JS, into a single JS file

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, requirejs

Is there any decent procedure to **compile** `html`, `css`, and `js` files into **one `js` file**? I've been looking on methods how to load `css` and `html` files to `js`, and they all require [requireJS](https://requirejs.org/). Is there any [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) plugin, or just a module for this?

I know this is not a decent question, but I've been thinking on not always fetching an external source file (`html`, `css`).

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Blah blah blah</title>
    <script src="something.js"></script>
    <script>
        // 'load' will load everthing to #something
        something.load(
            // options
        )
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="something"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That can all go into an HTML file. Of course, it's better to use external sources, as they are cached.

Comment: You should fetch external resources.

Comment: I get you guys, totally. But I need the JS file to load everything (css and html). It is totally doable in with requireJS, I'm thinking on options without it requireJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, thanks to this [article](https://hackernoon.com/using-html-components-with-webpack-f383797a5ca), all I need is [html-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/). Then I can just add `import html from 'some.html'`.